# How to run cmd commands via PHP script for initialize Websocket server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cmd, websocket, ratchet

I use [takielias](https://github.com/takielias/codeigniter-websocket-example) Codeigniter websocket in my project for notification purpose, first of all i am noob for websocket handshaking connection and WS protocol, here every thing working as per the takielias github page documentation, in his git hub page after all setup, need to run cmd command for run server client connection command is `php index.php welcome index` after run this command in the project path websocket connection is switched and every thing is working fine in my local, after uploading on server there i can't run this command manually,

so i need a help with this, run that command and execute the socket connection, then i decide to run that command via php script, but i can't able to execute that command successfully in local, if any other possible way to make a socket connection with client please assist me,

I really Appreciate your help,

Comment: Please use proper punctuation (period at the end of a sentence instead of comma). You should also start each sentence with a Capital letter. Right now, all the text is basically just one huge sentence which makes it harder to read. Also please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. You need to add all relevant code and explain the issue (what actually happens, potential errors etc)

Comment: now you can understand my problem or not?

Comment: Sorry, but if you can't bother even _trying_ to make the question more readable, I'm out...

Comment: please give a solution to me, if you can understand my problem, i am really struggling... : - (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you need to execute the command via php script. You can do so using `shell_exec` or `exec`.
See documentation here:
[exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)
[shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Example:
`shell_exec("/path/to/php /var/www/html/index.php welcome index '".$parmeter1."' '".$parmeter2."' >> /path/to/logs/welcome.log &");`

If you want to run the command in background then it is important to put & at the end.

The extra variables surrounded in single quotes after the path to the script are optional. You can omit them if not needed.

Comment: yes, i know using those function to run commands, can you please explain or give a code to execute "php index.php welcome index" this command

Comment: @Eibs I have added an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how can i use this in hosting server, what are the path i give, is there any way to get a dynamic path

Comment: @Eibs For path to your script you can check "DOCUMENT_ROOT" by printing `$_SERVER` and for path to php you can check in your command line using `whereis php` Generally it is /usr/bin/php

Comment: while i am running whereis php, it's return "whereis not recognized as an internal and external command"

Comment: i am using windows 7

Comment: For windows, you can try `where php.exe`

Comment: In my server php path command return "php: /usr/bin/php /usr/lib/php.ini /usr/lib/php /usr/local/bin/php /usr/local/lib/php.ini,v /usr/local/lib/php.ini /usr/local/lib/php /usr/include/php /usr/local/php" this value, is this correct value, when i am dyanamically run socket connection command nothing return on server, that's why i doubt with that returned php path

Comment: I really appriciate your valuable replies to me, thanks for your time : - )